# Error when trying to open pdf file from AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm new to Emacs and AUCTeX. On my home computer (with Windows XP) I can successfully compile .tex files and then, using C-c C-c again, launch a pdf viewer (Adobe Reader or Sumatra) to view the file.

However, on my work computer (Windows 7), I can successfully compile a .tex file to pdf using C-c C-c, but when I do C-c C-c again to view, the default view command that appears is `start "" "a.pdf"`. Pressing Enter brings up the Windows error message `Windows cannot find 'a.pdf'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.` If I change the command so that it includes the full location of the file, e.g. `start "" "//servername/mark/a.pdf"`, then the pdf viewer opens. At home, there is no need to change the default command `start "" "a.pdf"`.

I'd appreciate if anyone can tell me how to get the pdf viewer to open without having to edit the command each time. At work I have AUCTeX version 11.86.

Answer (score 3):

Your default PDF-viewer is controlled by two variables called `TeX-view-program-list` and `TeX-view-program-selection`. There are several ways of modifying these:

**Through the Emacs's interface**

```
M-x customize-group <RET>
AUCTeX
```

Select the group called: `Tex Command` then find `TeX View`. Under `TeX View Program List` is all the list of known commands for viewing your generated pdf. In my case I use SumatraPDF.exe  which I also have in my global `PATH` variable. Insert following:

```
Name: SumatraPDF
Command: SumatraPDF.exe %o
```

Under `TeX View Program Selection` the default viewer for pdf and dvi can be selected. Select the previously defined SumatraPDF.

**Inserting setup in .emacs**

Just insert following code in your `.emacs` configuration file:

```lisp
(setq TeX-output-view-style '("^pdf$" "." "SumatraPDF.exe %o"))

(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("SumatraPDF" "SumatraPDF.exe %o")
        ))
(cond
 ((eq system-type 'windows-nt)
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "SumatraPDF")
                                                 (output-dvi "Yap"))))))

 ((eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Okular")
                                                 (output-dvi "Okular")))))))
```

If you don't use SumatraPDF (I really recommend you do), then change the name and command. Remember to have your pdf-viewer in your PATH or refer directly to it through the full path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it didn't work. My problem doesn't seem to be in specifying the pdf viewer to be used, rather it is in specifying the location of the pdf file to be viewed. If I change the default command `start "" "a.pdf"` to `start "" "//servername/mark/a.pdf"` then it works with both Acrobat and Sumatra. What I'd like to know is how to get Emacs/AUCTeX to look for the pdf file in the same directory as the .tex file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue under Windows 7 and i accidentally found out a while ago that editing `start "" "a.pdf"` manually into `start "a.pdf"` opens Sumatra PDF correctly.
Following the beginning of the other answer, i figured out that i can solve the issue permanently by changing the corresponding `command` under `Tex Output View Style`, Extension `^pdf$`, accordingly from `start "" %o` to `start %o`. You find the option `Tex Output View Style` by starting with

```
M-x customize-group <RET> 
AUCTeX
```

and selecting the group `Tex Command`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it didn't work. When I use `start "a.pdf"` instead of `start "" "a.pdf"`, it opens another window with a command prompt (like a "DOS prompt"). I just open the pdf file manually, which I don't really mind.